# Read TDM file with python module "tdm_loader"

Tags: python, file, directory, python-module, labview

So i am trying to read a .tdm file with python and am using tdm_loader module.

Per

```
import numpy
import tdm_loader as tdm
data = tdm.OpenFile('DATA.TDM')
data.channel_name(0,0)
```

> data.channel_name(0,0)

> Out[2]: 'Time'

But:

> data.channel(0,0)

results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-ab5f07c9eb08>", line 1, in <module>
    data.channel(0,0)

  File "C:\Users\sebastian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tdm_loader\tdm_loader.py", line 231, in channel
    data_usi = OpenFile._get_usi_from_txt(lc.findtext('values'))[0]

*IndexError: list index out of range*
```

> data.channel(0,1)

gives another error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File "<ipython-input-7-248c388cba15>", line 1, in <module>
        data.channel(0,1)
    
      File "C:\Users\sebastian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tdm_loader\tdm_loader.py", line 238, in channel
        ext_attribs = self._root.find(".//file/block[@id='{0}']".format(inc.get('external'))).attrib
    
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'
```

I can access other .tdm files that go along with a .tdx file. But this .tdm file goes along with a .json and a .l03 file.
I don't know if this produces the problem? Any Advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A *.TDM file is usually nothing but a XML tree that describes the structure and type of the actual numerical data which is given in binary form in the associated *.TDX file. So the TDM itself only provides a bunch of meta-data but not the actual numerical measurement data. However, there is an extension of the TDM format called TDMS that features both meta- and binary data in a single file. There are also other packages available that decode this kind of format. Check it out at

- https://pypi.org/project/TDMtermite/
- https://github.com/RecordEvolution/TDMtermite

Comment: thx for the answer, i would like to try it! i tried importing it but it failed. i think i don't fulfill the "gcc version >= 10.2.0" but how do i update the gcc? I am using spyder and anaconda and would like to try your module.